Is there a solution to expired nonces in forms when using full page caching that doesn't involve configuring the cache?
Summary
I want to include a form in a WordPress page that includes a nonce field, and upon submission it validates the nonce, and for this to work fine when full page caching used.
Issue with full page caching
This works until a website uses a full page caching mechanism, as the page code is cached including the nonce field.
If the cache is not configured to regenerate every 10 hours or less then when submitting the form the nonce is going to be invalid. The 10 hours or less is based on this information, which is for the WP Rocket plugin, but appears to be the case for most caching mechanisms.
Therefore if you want to include a form in a WordPress page, and validate the nonce, on a website which has full page caching enabled, what is the solution? Is the only way to configure the cache to regenerate every 10 hours or less?
Note: that I am wanting to do the nonce check, in part, because when running WordPress Coding Standards phpcs (code sniffer) it will highlight an error that the form fields being submitted must be validated with a nonce.
Example:
Here is a very basic example form that I've included at the top of WordPress pages, a nonce field is generated and included in the form via wp_nonce_field, on submission it will display an "Nonce invalid" notice if the nonce could not be verified.

On websites without full page caching the nonce is valid

On websites with full page caching the nonce is invalid if the page being served from the cache is > 10 hours old
 function test_form() {
     ?>
     <form method="post">
         <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
         <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
         <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
         <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
         <?php wp_nonce_field( 'test_form', 'test_form_nonce' ); ?>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
     <?php
     if ( !wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['test_form_nonce'] ), 'test_form' ) ) {
         echo 'Nonce invalid';
     }
 }
 add_action( 'wp_head', 'test_form' );




If something on the page expires sooner than that pages cache then you will end up in this situation or an analogue/equivalent situation.
So in the strictest sense the answer is a hard no.
Either the nonce expiration has to increase, making the nonce less secure, the cache has to decrease so that the things being cached don't become stale, or that page/page fragment can't be cached. Everything else involves fundamentally changing what you're doing, e.g. pulling the form in via JS, using an iframe or embed of some sort, not using a nonce, etc
Note as well that WP doesn't just check if the nonce is currently valid, there's a grace period where it also checks the value the nonce would have had previously so that stale nonces don't just instantly expire.
Depending on your use case, the use of nonces here might not be correct, e.g. if it were a form int he admin area or for a privileged/logged in user to perform an action then a nonce is appropriate. But for lets say a contact form that has no authentication a nonce may not be appropriate. Gravity Forms for example does not uses nonces unless there are restrictions around the form or it requires user login.
As with most rules, PHPCS is there to catch issues and be a tool to better your code, but you shouldn't blindly implement its recommendations without considering the context. You can silence it with a comment, just be sure to add your own comment explaining why you aren't using nonces and what you've done instead to protect the form ( e.g. captchas ).
As for AJAX, it defeats the point of the nonce since now anybody can query to get the nonce from AJAX without opening the page, eliminating the point of having the nonce in the first place to ensure that the submission of the form came from that specific place. You also then run into the problem of cached AJAX entries, and that you might need a nonce to securely retrieve it putting you back at square one.

What do you think about the possible nonce via AJAX in the other answer?

it sort of defeats the point of having the nonce in the first place and adds complexity, assumes JS loads and works, and doesn't solve the original problem of you wanting to cache something for longer than it stays fresh. The food equivalent of this is syringing out off milk and putting new milk into the jug because your milk lasts a week but you only want to restock the fridge every 2 weeks

if I were you I'd instead look at changing the cache policy for just that page if it can't be done site-wide

This is to be included in a plugin, so ideally im looking for some solution that doesn't involve having to change cache policy - "it sort of defeats the point of having the nonce in the first place" would you mind explaining this for me? thanks

Note that if you're distributing this then this is one of those things were the problem can never truly be solved since you may end up on a site with multiple caching plugins and caching CDNs, documentation is the best remedy here. As for AJAX and nonces, the whole point of a nonce is to make sure that the form is submitted from that page and not via other nefarious means, if you aquire the nonce via an AJAX endpoint then that's no longer guaranteed, and you introduce the problem of cached AJAX endpoints giving stale nonces, nevermind those who modify nonce timings

I'd also think about why you want to add nonces, if the only reason you've added them is to shut up PHPCS then that is a mistake, similar to people who trash their sites performance in order to tick boxes on google lighthouse. Case in point Gravity Forms uses nonces but only for forms restricted to logged in users. The context of what your plugin does, the purpose of the form, and where the form is shown and to who is important here and can't be separated out

Also, you'll want a nonce for your AJAX request that returns a nonce if you want it to be secure, so it's a chicken egg situation

Nonces are unique per user session, so even if the AJAX request isn't protected by a nonce, the nonce from the AJAX request wouldn't be the same for someone else. https://developer.wordpress.org/news/2023/08/01/understand-and-use-wordpress-nonces-properly/#what-if-i-tell-you-that-wordpress-nonce-is-not-a-nonce

So lets say for example context, you added a hidden form field with some data and a nonce to an existing add to cart form that doesn't do a nonce check on a product page, and you verified the nonce only for logged in users. That means a non-logged in user could be sent a fishy link to add something to cart, and as no nonce check for guests they get something added to cart they didn't know about - is this what you mean by the purpose? So from that scenario it is then upto you to determine whether it is a risk to not include the nonce verify?

And in that scenario then the onus is on the customer to double check their cart is correct before placing an order (which most people I suspect do)

if you are using it for a cart then the nonce part is irrelevant, the site will be fundamentally broken by the caching policy as nobody can update their carts. In that case yes a nonce makes sense as adding a cart is not an anonymous thing but specific to you and your session, but you didn't ask about specific contexts that's a new question, I'm only here to answer the original question as it was written

you need to understand what nonce is for, it is for other sites to not be able to take advantage of you being logged in in your site and have the relevant cookies set, and send some post request mimicing as if you were interacting with your site. When the request has to have a nonce, even with wordpress's subpar implementation of the concept it is hard to guess in advance the correct value. This is why getting the nonce with unprotected request is wrong as the attacker can just get the nonce and use it in his attack. Non authors in a site rarely need a nonce.

The general recommendation is to use JavaScript with AJAX to dynamically populate the nonce (untested):
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_nonce', static function () : string {
    echo wp_create_nonce( 'test_form' );
} );

Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557755/how-to-call-ajax-in-wordpress on making the AJAX call.
let nonce = value_from_ajax_call;
document.querySelector( '#test_form_nonce' ).attr( 'value', nonce );


Wouldn't creating the nonce in the callback defeat the purpose of the nonce? It might be better to wp_localize_script() the nonce creation and pass it to the ajax request. Otherwise, I think you'd be in a situation where you're verifying a nonce directly after it's creation. I'm not sure how that localization works with the Caching mechanisms of WP Rocket though.

I wouldn't think so, but possible I'm not seeing your perspective thoroughly.

If I do nonce creation via wp_localize_script(), doesn't this just output a JS variable for the nonce in the page code, and therefore that would get cached the same as the one in my example form?
I feel like @calebs solution could work, I need to test this further

sure you can send the nonce via ajax but which nonce will you use in that request? otherwise you just make getting the nonce an easy open API. Anyway ajax adds load to the server which kind of defeats the point of caching.

The problem stems from trying to use nonce where there is no need in it. Nonce in general should protect form submittion (or any kind of mutating action done a privelaged user). It should be rare that a cached page is sent to a logged in user, therefor it will be generated dynamically and you can safely add the nonce without issues of cache expiry. On the server side you check the nonce only if the user is logged in.
